# Text to excel file input prompt

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with creating a excel. While I created macros before using the record function, it does not work for this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have to import a bunch of delimited text files into excel and while the wizard is of great help I'd like to automate the whole process.

What I did was to record the process of importing one file with the wizard.
When I rerun the recorded excel I get the following error, though:
"Run time error '5':
Invalid procedure or call argument"

When I debug it shows an error in the .CommandType = 0 line.

I have two questions, how do I get rid of the error message and more importantly, how can I change the code so that a file input window will pop up every time I run the macro? (I tried to embed the Application.GetOpenFilename() command, to no success, unfortunately)

Thank you already for any help!

Cheers,
dahlai

This is my code:

```
Sub ImportDataPeriod1()
'
' ImportDataPeriod1 Macro
'

'
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;F:\pETMEOH100 15xx DHAP.txt", Destination:=Range("$A$3"))
        .CommandType = 0
        .Name = "pETMEOH100 15xx DHAP"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 37
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 9, 1, 9, _
        9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 _
        , 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue 1**

I do not understand the existence of the `.CommandType = 0` line.

I have never seen this property perhaps because I have never imported the type of data for which it is valid.  According to the documentation I can find: it is not valid for text files, 0 is not a permitted value and it appears to be obsolete since I can only find it under Excel 2003 documentation.  I suggest you delete this line.

**Issue 2**

The Macro Recorder will not record some commands; for example the File Dialog command.  You have to type up your own File Dialog command.

**Issue 3**

`"TEXT;F:\pETMEOH100 15xx DHAP.txt"` is just a string.  The Macro Recorder has created it as a literal having got a value from File Dialog.  `TEXT;` is compulsory but the rest of the string can be created in whatever manner is convenient.

**Macro**

You say you have a bunch of delimited text files.  I have used the `AllowMultiSelect = True` parameter of File Dialog so several files can be selected at once.

I move the selected files to an array so I can access the path/file names after exiting the dialog.

I loop for each of these files and:

- Find or create an unused worksheet to which the file will be imported.
- Extract the file name from the path/file name by discarding the path and the extension.
- I use the file name as the name of the worksheet and the query
- Import the file.

Be careful with my import parameters.  My text files had a different delimiter, use UTF-7 encoding and only have 5 fields.  Use your parameters except for `.Add` and `.Name`.  Adjust my range as required.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ImportFiles()

  Dim Found As Boolean
  Dim InxFile As Long
  Dim InxWsht As Long
  Dim NameFileCrnt As String
  Dim PathFile() As String
  Dim Pos As Long
  Dim WshtNew As Worksheet

  ' Open the file dialog
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Show

    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
      Call MsgBox("No file selected", vbOKOnly)
      Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Copy the name and path of every file selected by the user to array PathFile
    ReDim PathFile(1 To .SelectedItems.Count)
    For InxFile = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
      PathFile(InxFile) = .SelectedItems(InxFile)
    Next

  End With

  For InxFile = 1 To UBound(PathFile)

    ' Find worksheet with name SheetX if one exists
    Found = False
    For InxWsht = 1 To Worksheets.Count
      If Left(Worksheets(InxWsht).Name, 5) = "Sheet" Then
        Worksheets(InxWsht).Activate
        Found = True
        Exit For
      End If
    Next

    If Not Found Then
      ' No free worksheet for this file
      Set WshtNew = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
    End If

    ' Active sheet (existing or new) is the sheet to which file is to be imported

    ' Extract file name from path name
    Pos = InStrRev(PathFile(InxFile), "\")
    If Pos = 0 Then
      ' No folder name.  Don't think this is possible.
      NameFileCrnt = PathFile(InxFile)
    Else
      ' Extract text after final \
      NameFileCrnt = Mid(PathFile(InxFile), Pos + 1)
    End If
    Pos = InStrRev(NameFileCrnt, ".")
    If Pos = 0 Then
      ' No extension
    Else
      ' Discard text after final .
      NameFileCrnt = Mid(NameFileCrnt, 1, Pos - 1)
    End If

    ' Use file name without path and extension as name of worksheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = NameFileCrnt

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables _
      .Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & PathFile(InxFile), _
           Destination:=Range("A1"))        'Note I import to A1 not A3 as you do
      .Name = NameFileCrnt
      ' Replace the following with your values.  My test files
      ' had a different delimiter and were in UTF-7 format.
      ' Also I do not discard the initial rows of the file.
      ' to
      .FieldNames = True
      .RowNumbers = False
      .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
      .PreserveFormatting = True
      .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
      .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
      .SavePassword = False
      .SaveData = True
      .AdjustColumnWidth = True
      .RefreshPeriod = 0
      .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
      .TextFilePlatform = -535
      .TextFileStartRow = 1
      .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
      .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
      .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
      .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
      .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
      .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
      .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
      .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
      .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
      .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
      .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

  Next

End Sub
```